# API key or Cognito or both for mobile apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, security, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a mobile apps for iOS and Android, but now while configuring the APIs I didn't understand when should I use Cognito to Authorize the request and when should I use the API Key, or do I have to use them both, BTW I attach the userID in the request body whenever I need to get/send user data.

here is an image of how the structure looks like

[AWS Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCmO4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Cognito: that way you can trust the user identifiers forwarded to you Lambda function. Even though you send the `userId` in the payload, this is entirely built by the user/client and a malicious client could send any value, opening up a security risk. There's also the security of the API key to consider.

By the way, your private Lambdas don't have to be in public subnets (based on your attached diagram).